# Replace multiple cells

Tags: vba, excel, replace

I'm looking for a way to simplify my code. Perhaps using an array if possible? Any assistance would be much appreciated.

```
Cells.Replace What:="Invoice EMEA Payment", Replacement:="Invoice", LookAt:=xlWhole
On Error Resume Next
Cells.Replace What:="Invoice EMEA No Payment", Replacement:="Invoice", LookAt:=xlWhole
On Error Resume Next
Cells.Replace What:="Invoice USA Payment", Replacement:="Invoice", LookAt:=xlWhole
On Error Resume Next
Cells.Replace What:="Invoice USA No Payment", Replacement:="Invoice", LookAt:=xlWhole
On Error Resume Next
Cells.Replace What:="Invoice1 Lite EMEA Payment", Replacement:="Invoice1 Lite", LookAt:=xlWhole
On Error Resume Next
Cells.Replace What:="Invoice1 Lite EMEA No Payment", Replacement:="Invoice1 Lite", LookAt:=xlWhole
On Error Resume Next
Cells.Replace What:="Invoice1 Lite USA Payment", Replacement:="Invoice1 Lite", LookAt:=xlWhole
On Error Resume Next
Cells.Replace What:="Invoice1 Lite USA No Payment", Replacement:="Invoice1 Lite", LookAt:=xlWhole
On Error Resume Next
```

Comment: You could wrap these well-established strings in a `string` array stored in a global-type sub, then iterate over it... Storing this kind of repeatable and re-usable info in a global sub can be a major time-saver.

Answer (score 1):

Try this out:

```
Option Explicit

Global ReplaceText(8, 2) As String ' <~ set up a global array of strings and replacements

'build out all of our global constants here
Sub MyVariables()
    ReplaceText(1, 1) = "Invoice EMEA Payment"
    ReplaceText(1, 2) = "Invoice"
    ReplaceText(2, 1) = "Invoice No EMEA Payment"
    ReplaceText(2, 2) = "Invoice"
    ReplaceText(3, 1) = "Invoice USA Payment"
    ReplaceText(3, 2) = "Invoice"
    ReplaceText(4, 1) = "Invoice USA No Payment"
    ReplaceText(4, 2) = "Invoice"
    ReplaceText(5, 1) = "Invoice1 Lite EMEA Payment"
    ReplaceText(5, 2) = "Invoice1 Lite"
    ReplaceText(6, 1) = "Invoice1 Lite EMEA No Payment"
    ReplaceText(6, 2) = "Invoice1 Lite"
    ReplaceText(7, 1) = "Invoice1 Lite USA Payment"
    ReplaceText(7, 2) = "Invoice1 Lite"
    ReplaceText(8, 1) = "Invoice1 Lite USA No Payment"
    ReplaceText(8, 2) = "Invoice1 Lite"
End Sub

'implement the find and replace
Sub FindAndReplace()

Dim Idx As Long
Dim MySheet As Worksheet

Call MyVariables ' <~ call the MyVariables sub and boom, you've got the ReplaceText array

Set MySheet = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet
With MySheet
    For Idx = 1 To UBound(ReplaceText)
        .Cells.Replace What:=ReplaceText(Idx, 1), _
            Replacement:=ReplaceText(Idx, 2), LookAt:=xlWhole
    Next Idx
End With

End Sub
```

Now that you've got a handy `MyVariables` sub, you can store any and all `global` variables there.