# Using classes instead of global variables in vba

Tags: vba, excel

Excel VBA won't let you use global variables of arrays so I am trying to use a class to keep track of the variables I need.  I am trying to create the variable in one sub and call it from another, but I don't know how to do it.

```
Sub Test3()
 Dim mc As cVars
 Set mc = New cVars

 Dim ex() As Double
 ReDim ex(1 To 5)

 For i = 1 To 5
  ex(i) = i
 Next i

 mc.Arr = ex

 Call Test4
End Sub

Sub Test4()
 Dim out() As Double
 ReDim out(1 To 5)
 out = mc.Arr

 MsgBox (out(2))
End Sub
```

...

```
Option Explicit
Private pArr() As Double
Public Property Get Arr() As Double()
    Arr = pArr()
End Property
Public Property Let Arr(p() As Double)
    pArr = p()
End Property
```

The error comes in Test4() because there is no mc initiated, I tried initiating it but it then is not the same class (I believe)

Comment: I can set a `Public` variable that's an array of `Doubles` in one module and refer to it in another module.

Comment: I think @DougGlancy is right here, I actually constructed a `global string` array in my answer not five minutes ago... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23419422/excel-vba-replace-multiple-cells/23420640#23420640

Comment: I try to add "Public Inputs() as Double" to the beginning and I get an error that says "Compile error: Constants, fixed-length strings, arrays, user-defined types and Declare statements not allowed as Public members of object modules." I've tried using "Global" instead of Public as well

Comment: Got it, I was in Excel Objects but I guess I should be putting my code in Modules?  It seems to be working now, thanks

Comment: Sorry, I should have specified that it needs to be a regular module. Glad you figured it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not change `Sub Test4()` to a function instead calling a variable mc:

```
Function Test4(mc As cVars)
    Dim out() As Double
    ReDim out(1 To 5)
    out. mc.Arr

    MsgBox(out(2))
End Function
```

That may work.